# i3wm screen locking security issue

Tags: security, lock-screen, i3-wm

I am using i3-wm on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am locking the screen using `dm-tool lock`, and it looks good, but I noticed you can circumvent the lock screen by switching a TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and then switching back to the graphical TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F7).

Doing so will hide the lock screen and show the desktop, even if no password was given.

Is this a known issue? Am I locking the screen incorrectly?

Comment: Your command for locking screen works OK on Ubuntu 14.04.4. I tried it now and I still had to enter password. So it seems version specific. Maybe a bug?